# MS Access export query to Excel file template

Tags: ms-access

I want to create some VBA code to open an existing Excel workbook, transfer the query to a new sheet and save the file with todays date and time. So far this is the code I

```
Private Sub cmd_planning_report_Click()

    Dim ExportNumber As String
    Dim ExportFileName As String
    Dim ProjectPath As String
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TemplatePath As String

    ProjectPath = CurrentProject.Path
    FolderPath = "Report_Templates"
    FilePath = "Template.xlsx"
    TemplatePath = ProjectPath & "\" & FolderPath & "\" & FilePath
    ExportNumber = Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_HHMMss")
    ExportFileName = "my_report_" & ExportNumber & ".xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "A1_Report", TemplatePath, True

End Sub
```

Which works as the query is exported to Template.xlsx but I would like it to save the file as ExportFileName

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need this twist:

```
ProjectPath = CurrentProject.Path
FolderPath = "Report_Templates"
ExportNumber = Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_HHMMss")
ExportFileName = "my_report_" & ExportNumber & ".xlsx"
TemplatePath = ProjectPath & "\" & FolderPath & "\" & ExportFileName
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution, the original TemplatePath is the Excel template file I want to open and have the query exported to and then save as ExportFileName

Comment: Then you must open Excel using automation and call "Save As ..".

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the file once it is saved in the template with

```
NAME TemplatePath AS ExportFileName
```

Or make a copy of the file with the new name.

```
Dim fso As MyObject

Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile TemplatePath, ExportFileName
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it then changes the templates file, so any query that then gets exported to it will be query...query1...query2.

Comment: Could you make a copy at the beginning of your script and then export the query to the copy?